# Como utilizar valor de um contador dentro de função assíncrona

Tags: javascript, node.js

Gostaria de saber se tenho como passar algum valor externo para dentro da função assíncrona mantendo o valor de quando a função foi chamada.

```
for(x=0;x<array.length;x++){
       fs.readfile(path,function(error,file){
          console.log(file.data == array[x]);
       });
    }
```

Quando executo a leitura do arquivo dentro do laço a função assíncrona sempre dispara depois de o laço terminar a execução, não ficando com o valor de quando a leitura iniciou.

Para solucionar isso acabei chamando a leitura de arquivo de forma síncrona

```
    for(x=0;x<array.length;x++){
       file = fs.readfileSync(path);
       console.log(file.data == array[x]);
    }
```

Mas não sei se é a melhor solução, e gostaria de saber se existe uma maneira de passar o valor de X para dentro da função assíncrona pois nem todas as funções vão ter uma alternativa síncrona como é o caso da `readFile`.

Comment: Use `let x = 0` em vez de `x = 0`